# how to convert frameset to iframe

Tags: html, jsp

My code is structured as a frameset.

I want to change this to iframe format.

```
<frameset rows="49px, *, 22%, 0" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0"> 
<frame src="/vew/DS_Top.jsp" name="DS_Top" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" border="0" noresize>
<frameset cols= "550, *" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">
<frame src="/vew/DS_Main.jsp" name="DS_Main" border="0" frameborder="0">
<frame src="/vew/DS_Left.jsp" name="DS_Left"  border="0" frameborder="0">
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------
                  DS_Top
--------------------------------------------------------
                 |
                 |
                 |
    DS_Main      |             DS_Left
                 |
                 |
                 |
               DS_Sub
-------------------------------------------------------
 height=0 : DS_White
```

I tried this but it did not work

```css
.DSmain {
  width: 550px;
  height: calc(100% - 22% - 49px);
  position: absolute;
}

.DSleft {
  height: calc(100% - 22% - 49px);
  width: calc(100% - 566px);
  margin-left: 550px;
  position: absolute;
}

.DSsub {
  width: 100%;
  height: 22%;
  margin-top: calc(100%-22%-49px);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
Using ajavascript:'string' to show which file goes where
<hr/>

<iframe src="javascript:'/vew/DS_Top.jsp'" width="100%" height="49px;" frameborder=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 scrolling=no></iframe>
<iframe src="javascript:'/vew/DS_Main.jsp'" class="DSmain" frameborder=0 framespacing=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0></iframe>
<iframe src="javascript:'/vew/DS_Left.jsp'" class="DSleft" frameborder=0 framespacing=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0></iframe>
<iframe src="javascript:'/vew/DS_Sub.jsp'" class="DSsub" frameborder=0 framespacing=0 scrolling=no marginheight=0 marginwidth=0></iframe>
<iframe src="javascript:'/vew/DS_White.jsp'" width="100%" height="0px;" frameborder=0 framespacing=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 scrolling=no></iframe>
```

Comment: Why not divs with includes?

Comment: I made you a snippet to show the code better.

Comment: you have to use div tag as per expected design and inside it you can use Iframe

Comment: Thank you for answer.
What is the height of this mark(*)?